# how to make a loop and fix inaccessible code?

Tags: c#

I'm making a little program which will update the value of a string from a website and put it into a textbox. I think I've got this nearly done, but i'm not sure how i could make it repeat itself and I have a couple errors
Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
'Form1.textBox1' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

> - I know i can fix the static main issue (even though it is static) by removing async, but then how could i implement a loop?
> - what is making textBox 1 inaccessible and how can i fix it? its in a seperate .cs file which is included in the project

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
static class Program
{
    static async void Main() // program does not contain a static Main method??
    {
        Form1 Buttons = new Form1();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        try
        {
            MatchCollection matches;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.coinbase.com/api/v2/prices/USD/spot?");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            string pattern = "BTC\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"amount\":\"([^\"]*)";
            Regex responsex = new Regex(pattern);
            matches = responsex.Matches(responseBody);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Buttons.textBox1.Text = matches; // Form1.textBox1 is inaccessible due to its protection level
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException)
        {
            return;
        }

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

}

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public bool Play;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Play = !Play;
        if (Play == true)
        {
            button1.Text = "Pause";
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Text = "Resume";
        }
    }

    public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: To fix the second issue select `textBox1` in designer and  change its `Modifiers` property (in properties windows) to `Public`

Comment: You shouldn’t be running that code there. It doesn’t belong in startup method. You’ll also fix the other problem by moving the code where it belongs: to the form.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thanks, this worked flawlessly. how can i get it to loop now?

Comment: Loop how and what?

Comment: sorry about that, i got it all working... but after a bit of work it seems my regex doesn't return the right value. instead of returning just the capture group, it returns everything in the string while executing the capture.